# 2 сайта на 1 vds

Tags: php, apache, apache2, vps, vds

Всем привет
У меня есть VDS и я хочу разместить на нём сразу несколько сайтов

я хочу чтобы на
mine.Ltmc.fun был авто дон
а на
zkhost.space был другой сайт

но чтобы 2 сайта стояло на 1 хосте

пробывал создать var/www/zkhost.space но не получается

Что делать как сделать чтобы на 1 вдс было 2 сайта под разными доменами

http://zkhost.space/hosting_v2.0/index.html 1 сайт
http://mine.ltmc.fun/ 2 сайт

Comment: Прописать нужные виртуальные хосты в настройках веб-сервера

Comment: а как это сделать через SSH

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант сделать через `.htaccess`. Может это и извращение, зато не нужно возиться с виртуальными хостами

Создайте в `/var/www/` файл `.htaccess`, и прописывайте следующее

```
RewriteEngine On

# Сайт mine.Ltmc.fun
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mine\.ltmc\.fun$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/mine\.ltmc\.fun/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mine\.ltmc\.fun/$1 [L]

# Сайт zkhost.space
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zkhost\.space$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/zkhost\.space/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /zkhost\.space/$1 [L]
```

А свои сайты храните в папках `/var/www/mine.ltmc.fun` и `/var/www/zkhost.space` соответственно. На работу самих сайтов это никак повлиять не должно (если, конечно, где-нибудь в скриптах ещё не прописаны абсолютные пути для каких-либо в файлов на сайте. Если это так, то придётся переписывать), в том числе и на `.htaccess`.